# Spring MVC ,JSON,@RequestBody android as client

Tags: android, spring-mvc

Here my requirement is getting data from android client and posting those values to the database.Middle level layer is Spring MVC.How to get values from android client to web service? I already have done sample example that is with normal rest web service.I resolved it by using MultivaluedMapping.How to do it in Spring MVC.
Thanks for your valuable suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot makes what you want extremely simple, as 1) it handles most of the configuration automatically (for example it ads Jackson 2 to Spring MVC for seamless JSON handling), 2) it has awesome defaults that meat the needs of RESTFul web services.

Check out the guides section from Spring's site and more specifically the following ones:

[1](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/),[2](http://spring.io/guides/gs/device-detection/),[3](http://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/),[4](http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/),[5](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/)